# Getting string from python within nested parentheses

Tags: python, python-2.x, text-parsing

I have a string like

> (0 (1 (2 (3 (4 (5 The) (6 room)) (7 (8 was) (9 (10 very) (11 good))))
>   (12 but)) (13 (14 (15 the) (16 food)) (17 (18 was) (19 (20 very) (21
>   bad))))) (22 .))

Which actually is a tree :

[image]

I want to get achieve having string for a given node, i.e. if a say node 0 I should recieve "The room was very good but food was bad." if I say node 2 I should receive "The room was very good but" and for node 5 "The" and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You know, without showing any effort yourself, you won't receive help here either. In particular not for a question that screams "homework" like yours.

Comment: The obvious answer is: parse that string into a tree structure and use that structure to get the desired information. Have you already tried that? If so, where exactly did you encounter a problem?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am sorry. Honestly, this is not a homework but a small part of a project. I don't know much of RegEx so I couldn't even start the task.

Comment: @Carsten, How to parse this string into tree?

Comment: Can you write code to create the tree that you envision without parsing the string? If you have no idea how the results should look like, get some inspiration from random Python code or tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first build the obvious tree (where nodes have children nodes and possibly a string payload) then process it to get the alternative you want (with a string including children's payloads).  E.g, a rough draft (no error-checking &c):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.children = []
        self.text = []
        self.payload = self.wholestring = ''

def make_payload_tree(astring):
    root = Node(-1)
    parents = [root]
    sit = iter(astring)
    for c in sit:
        if c=='(':
            mkn = []
            for c in sit:
                if c==' ': break
                mkn.append(c)
            newnode = Node(int(''.join(mkn)))
            parents[-1].children.append(newnode)
            parents.append(newnode)
        elif c==')':
            oldnode = parents.pop()
            oldnode.payload = ''.join(oldnode.text)
        else:
            parents[-1].text.append(c)
  return root
```

You can roughly verify that this payload-tree is correct e.g with:

```
def print_tree(r, ind=0):
    print ' '*ind, r.n, r.payload, r.wholestring
    for c in r.children:
        print_tree(c, ind + 2)
```

Of course, at this point, the `wholestring` will still be empty strings.

Now, a second pass lets you build the `wholestring` attributes:

```
def makewhole(node):
    for c in node.children:
        makewhole(c)
    s = node.payload + ' '.join(c.wholestring for c in node.children)
    node.wholestring = s.replace('  ', ' ')
```

and the `print_tree` should verify you have the `wholestring`s you want.

Now the **interesting** part is to put in place proper error diagnosis (this code is quite frail if there is any "syntax error" in the input string, and the syntax thereof is implied by your example, never made explicit), but that's probably best done with a proper lexer and parser approach rather than with ad-hoc parsing like I'm doing here.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the string using [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/):

```
s='(0 (1 (2 (3 (4 (5 The) (6 room)) (7 (8 was) (9 (10 very) (11 good)))) (12 but)) (13 (14 (15 the) (16 food)) (17 (18 was) (19 (20 very) (21 bad))))) (22 .))'

from pyparsing import *
enclosed = Forward()
nestedParens = nestedExpr('(', ')', content=enclosed) 
enclosed << (Word(alphanums+'.') | ',' | nestedParens)

>>> enclosed.parseString(s).asList()  
[['0', ['1', ['2', ['3', ['4', ['5', 'The'], ['6', 'room']], ['7', ['8', 'was'], ['9', ['10', 'very'], ['11', 'good']]]], ['12', 'but']], ['13', ['14', ['15', 'the'], ['16', 'food']], ['17', ['18', 'was'], ['19', ['20', 'very'], ['21', 'bad']]]]], ['22', '.']]]
```

Then deal with the nested data as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, how to parse the string.

Each `node` looks like `({number} {word | node node})`, where `number` is `\d+` and `word` is `[\w,.]+`. This description fits itself perfectly to a recursive descent parser.

The second question is, how do I store the resulting tree such that I can find a node and its descendants easily.

I would suggest a `dict` indexed by node number - something like

```
tree = {
    0: (1, 22),
    1: (2, 13),
    2: (3, 12),
    # ...
    20: "very",
    21: "bad",
    22: "."
}
```

This allows you to jump directly to any node, and follow the tree from there to recreate the sentence-fragment.

Comment: The sentence could be of any length, so I cannot simply define the children of any particular node.